# VBA replacing text without formatting

Tags: xml, vba, replace, docx

In a docx-file, I have a lot of text which may contain specific notation for  math objects (mml). These notations are enclosed withing certain delimiter (MATHSTART and MATHEND) so that they can be looked for.

Example:

```
MATHSTART<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block" alttext="x equals StartFraction negative b plus-or-minus StartRoot b squared minus 4 a c EndRoot Over 2 a EndFraction">
  <semantics>
    <mrow>
      <mi>x</mi>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
        <mfrac>
          <mrow>
            <mo>−<!-- − --></mo>
            <mi>b</mi>
            <mo>±<!-- ± --></mo>
            <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
              <msqrt>
                <msup>
                  <mi>b</mi>
                  <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
                    <mn>2</mn>
                  </mrow>
                </msup>
                <mo>−<!-- − --></mo>
                <mn>4</mn>
                <mi>a</mi>
                <mi>c</mi>
              </msqrt>
            </mrow>
          </mrow>
          <mrow>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>a</mi>
          </mrow>
        </mfrac>
      </mrow>
    </mrow>
    <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">x={-b\pm {\sqrt {b^{2}-4ac}} \over 2a}</annotation>
  </semantics>
</math>MATHEND
```

I now want to use a marcos to fetch all these parts and cut them from the document, then putting them back in again without the delimiters (MATHSTART and MATHEND) and without the format (something like `wdFormatPlainText`). The desired result is a math equation in the docx.

[image: docx math equation object]

What i have so far:

```
Dim regex As Object, wholeDocText As String
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy
wholeDocText = Selection.Text

With regex
    .Pattern = "MATHSTART[.\s\S]*?MATHEND"
    .Global = True
End With

Set matches = regex.Execute(wholeDocText)

For Each match In matches
    s1 = Replace(match.Value, "MATHSTART", "")
    s1 = Replace(s1, "MATHEND", "")

    'select match.Value in the document
    'overwrite the selected string with the new one
    'sth like: Selection.Text s1(wdFormatPlainText)
Next match
```

The problem are the three lines of comment, which I don't know how to implement.

Comment: Simply writing `match = s1` instead of the commented code?

Comment: @Vityata that simply changes the value of the variable, but i need the script to mark the text-part in the document so that it then gets overwritten (without formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I utilised the search-and-select functionality from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34020540/8696721)

```
Sub convertMmlToWordField()

Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String
Dim FindStartRange As Range, FindEndRange As Range
Dim CopyRange As Range, CopyStartRange As Range, CopyEndRange As Range

Set FindStartRange = ActiveDocument.Range
Set FindEndRange = ActiveDocument.Range
Set CopyRange = ActiveDocument.Range

StartWord = "MATHSTART"
EndWord = "MATHEND"

'Starting the Lookup for the starting word
With FindStartRange.find
    .Text = StartWord
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

    'Execute the Lookup
    Do While .Execute
        If .Found = True Then
            Set CopyStartRange = FindStartRange
            CopyStartRange.Select

            'Setting the FindEndRange up for the remainder of the document beginning from the end of the StartWord 
            FindEndRange.Start = CopyStartRange.End
            FindEndRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End
            FindEndRange.Select

            'Setting the Find to look for the End Word
            With FindEndRange.find
                .Text = EndWord
                .Execute

                If .Found = True Then
                    Set CopyEndRange = FindEndRange
                    CopyEndRange.Select
                End If
            End With

            'Selecting the copy range
            CopyRange.Start = CopyStartRange.Start
            CopyRange.End = CopyEndRange.End
            CopyRange.Select

            s1 = Replace(CopyRange.Text, "MATHSTART", "")
            s1 = Replace(s1, "MATHEND", "")

            Selection.Text = s1
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
        End If      'Ending the If Find1stRange .Found = True
    Loop        'Ending the Do While .Execute Loop
End With    'Ending the Find1stRange.Find With Statement

End Sub
```

The actual work happens in this part:

```
s1 = Replace(CopyRange.Text, "MATHSTART", "")
s1 = Replace(s1, "MATHEND", "")

Selection.Text = s1
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
```

CopyRange is the entire string from MATHSTART to MATHEND (inclusive).
So you can just cut those parts.
What's left is the actual MML, which you can now feed into the Selection object (replacing the string in the document), then copy and pasting it without the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In case that you only want to remove two words per RegEx.Match, the following should work:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim regex As Object, wholeDocText As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Copy
    wholeDocText = Selection.Text

    With regex
        .Pattern = "MATHSTART[.\s\S]*?MATHEND"
        .Global = True
    End With

    Set matches = regex.Execute(wholeDocText)

    For Each match In matches
        s1 = Replace(match, "MATHSTART", "")
        s1 = Replace(s1, "MATHEND", "")
        match = s1
    Next match

End Sub
```

---

I have removed the `.Value` from the first `Replace()` and I have added `match = s1`.